# Square brackets overloading => no operator matches operands

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, brackets

I'm currently having a bit of trouble overloading the square brackets in a custom vector class.

My class basically looks like this:

```
typedef uint32_t u32; // This is not actually here, but so you get the idea. Also, it is included in the problematic call's file

template<class T>
class JFFVector
{
public:
    //Init and stuff
    T& operator[](u32 iIndex)
    {
        return m_pData[iIndex + miDataOffset];
    }

private:
    T* m_pData;
    u32 m_iDataOffset;
}
```

And within this classes functions, I can call (*this)[0] and everything works.
Now the issue I'm having is with a class that has a member as follows:

```
class TOtherClass
{
public:
    // Stuff
    void DoSomething() const
    {
        for (u32 i; i < m_tItems.size(); ++i)
            m_tItems[i]->DoStuff(); // Which is a const function
    }

private:
    JFFVector<const JFFItem*> m_tItems;
}
```

The issue being that my compiler throws an error at my face saying

> no operator "[]" matches these operands
>
> operand types are: const JFFVector[u32]
>
> typedef uint32_t u32.

So one thing I noticed is that if I make m_tItems a pointer, then I can do "(*m_tItems)[i]->DoStuff()" and it works fine. But I do not understand why this works while it doesn't with a non-pointer version.
(Also, I tried with a simple int instead of u32, and, with no surprise, it didn't work)

Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong please? And, if not trivial, why is it wrong?

(Sorry if this has been answered already, I tried searching for a similar issue but found nothing that looks like this issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two indexing operators you can overload -- one which works on a `const JFFVector` and returns a `T const&`, and one which works on a `JFFVector` and returns a `T&`. You've only implemented the second.

You can implement it similarly to the non-const version like so:

```
T const& operator[](u32 iIndex) const   // <-- note the two `const`s
{
    return m_pData[iIndex + miDataOffset];
}
```

Note that this overloading is not specific to `operator[]`, but rather all methods (which can be overloaded by `const` or non-`const`).

The reason you need the const version in your code is that `DoSomething()` is declared `const`, thus `this` is `const TOtherClass*` within that method, and by extension all its members, notably `m_tItems` here, are `const` within the method, and so only `const` methods can be called on them. Since there is no `const` version of `operator[]` defined for `m_tItems`, the compiler gives you that error.

Comment: Right. Dayum. I actually fell for that mistake.
Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

When in `const`, one must stay `const`. The compiler has no easy way to know that what happens in `m_tItems[i]` does not change `m_tItems` and thus violate the promise that `void DoSomething() const` would not change the state of `TOtherClass`.

Solution: Implement a `const` `operator[]`

```
const T& operator[](u32 iIndex) const 
{
    return m_pData[iIndex + miDataOffset];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 version, one for `const` and one without `const`. One for the immutable `const JFFVector` and one for mutable `JFFVector`.

In this case, `DoSomething` is a const function, it want to call a const function.

```
template<class T>
class JFFVector
{
public:
    //Init and stuff
    T& operator[](u32 iIndex)
    {
        return m_pData[iIndex + miDataOffset];
    }
    const T& operator[](u32 iIndex) const
    {
        return m_pData[iIndex + miDataOffset];
    }

private:
    T* m_pData;
    u32 m_iDataOffset;
}
```